# How do I open my own inventory via a Event?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to open up my inventory whenever I pick up an item. This is in Bukkit.

Here is the event so far, the arguments for `player.openInventory` are empty.

```
@EventHandler
public void blank(PlayerDropItemEvent e){
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    player.openInventory();
}
```

Comment: Did you `register` the listener?

Comment: The plugin works, the player.openInventory() needs an Argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `player.getInventory()` to retrieve their inventory then using `player.openInventory(inventory)` to open it.

```
@EventHandler
public void blank(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    Inventory inventory = player.getInventory();
    player.openInventory(inventory);
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to add, I like to do a quick `player.closeInventory()` before I open the inventory. It's probably not necessary, but the server doesn't know if the client already has their inventory open, and knowing mojang, it just might break the client if the server tries to tell them to open another inventory when they already have one open.

Comment: @hintss they actually did it ok, opening a inventory will automatically close the last inventory, it will even call a InventoryCloseEvent. ^_^

Comment: and will the client always be smart enough to do this, forever and ever? That's the important question.

Answer (score 3):

To get a player's inventory, you could use:

```java
player.getInventory();
```

If you wanted to open the player's inventory, you could use:

```java
player.openInventory(player.getInventory());
```

So, your code could look something like this:

```java
@EventHandler
public void dropItem(PlayerDropItemEvent e){
    Player player = e.getPlayer(); //get the player that dropped the item
    player.openInventory(player.getInventory()); //open the player's inventory
}
```